# Is there a way to print a variable, alter the same variable and print the two of them in a list?

Tags: java, loops, variables, user-input

First off I'm sorry if this is a wierd one, but I don't exactly know what I'm trying to do in coding terms.

To clarify what I wish to do, I want to know a way to "Save" the value of `receipt` to either a list/set/array then go trough the process that determined the value of `receipt` and save that to the list again, and when I print the list the two different values of receipt are printed after eachoter.
Lets say first time the value of `receipt` was determined it was equal to x, then after I've saved that to a list and gone trough the same value determening process `receipt`= y and I add that to the list. Would it print: x and then y. Or y and y? And if it prints the new value of `receipt` twice, how do I make it print the two different values after eachother?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicketV005
{ // start of public class
public static void main (String [] args)
{ // start of main
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int printedTickets,ticketTotal;
    String fareType, purchaseLoc;
    String answer1 =("null");
    String receipt =("null");
    int zoneAmount = 0;
    double price = 0;
    int answer2 = 0;

    System.out.print("How many tickets do you wish to buy?(Answer with a number please.) ");
    ticketTotal = keyboard.nextInt();
    printedTickets = 0;

    while (ticketTotal <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println("\nIncorrect input, try again.");
        System.out.println("How many tickets do you wish to buy?(Answer with a number please.) ");
        ticketTotal = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    while(ticketTotal !=printedTickets )
    {
        System.out.print("Welcome! Are you buying a reduced fare ticket?(y/n) ");
        answer1 = keyboard.next();

        if (answer1.equals("y"))
            fareType=("reduced fare");

        else if (answer1.equals("n"))
            fareType=("standard fare");

        else
            fareType=("null");

        while (fareType.equals("null"))
        {
            System.out.println("\nIncorrect input, try again.");
            System.out.println("Welcome! Are you buying a reduced fare ticket?(y/n) ");
            answer1 = keyboard.next();
        }

        System.out.println("Would you like to purchase your ticket at 1. the automated services or at 2. the cashier? ");
        answer2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (answer2 ==1)
            purchaseLoc=("automated services");

        else if (answer2 ==2)
            purchaseLoc=("cashier");

        else
            purchaseLoc=("null");

        while (purchaseLoc.equals("null"))
        {
            System.out.println("\nIncorrect input, try again.");
            System.out.println("Would you like to purchase your ticket at 1. the automated services or at 2. the cashier? ");
            answer2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("How many zones will you be travelling? (1-3) ");
        zoneAmount = keyboard.nextInt();    

        while (zoneAmount <= 0 || zoneAmount > 3 )
        {
            System.out.println("\nIncorrect input, try again.");
            System.out.println("How many zones will you be travelling? (1-3) ");
            zoneAmount = keyboard.nextInt();
        }   

         //Start of reduced fare
            if (answer1.equals("y") && answer2 == 1 ) 
            { // Start of automated services reduced fare

                for (int i= 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++)
                {
                    if (zoneAmount == i)
                    price=(10*i)+10;
                }
            } //end off automated services reduced fare

            if (answer1.equals("y") && answer2 == 2) 
            { // Start of cashier reduced fare

                for (int i= 1 ; i <=3 ; i++)
                {
                    if (zoneAmount == i)
                    price=(14*i)+14;
                }

            } //End of cashier reduced fare

        //End of reduced fare

        //Start of standard fare
            if (answer1.equals("n") && answer2==1) 
            { //Start of standard fare automated services

                for (int i = 1; i <=3 ; i++)
                {
                    if ( zoneAmount ==i)
                    price=(18*i)+18;
                }

            } // end of standard fare automated servies

            if (answer1.equals("n") && answer2==2)
            { // Start of standard fares cashier

                for (int i = 1; i <=3 ; i++)
                {
                    if( zoneAmount == i)
                    price=(22*i)+22;
                }

            } // End of standard fares cashier
        //End of standard fare

        System.out.println("");

        receipt = (zoneAmount+" zone(s), "+ fareType+", bought at: "+ purchaseLoc+". Your price: "+price+" SEK.");
        System.out.println(receipt);
        printedTickets++;   

        System.out.println(""); //Empty line for when/if it repeats

    } // end of while printedTickets is not equal to ticketTotal



}// end of main
}// end of public class
```

Edit1: Included full code for clarity.
Edit2: Better Clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're asking two questions. One relates to whether you can save a variable and the other is about how to have a bunch of things aggregated together. From your code it's not clear what your aims are.

In java, the things you declare, like

```
String receipt
```

are references. This means they keep track of a piece of data. However, other things can also keep track of that same piece of data. So:

```
String receipt1 = "100EUR";
String receipt2 = receipt1;
```

In the above code, there's only one thing in memory with "100EUR" in it, and both receipt1 and receipt2 are looking at it. If something came along and modified one of them

```
receipt1 = "200EUR";
```

The other would be unaffected.

```
System.out.println(receipt1);
System.out.println(receipt2);

// output would be 
        200EUR
        100EUR
```

In a lot of cases once something has been assigned to a reference via the = symbol, you can imagine that the reference is always going to have access to it, unchanged until the next time the = symbol is used to assign the reference to point to something else. However, in Java objects can change state, so if you had

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>():
```

and things started calling methods on `myList` to modify its contents, then the myList reference would feel like it's referring to something that changes. The reference itself is not changing, just the object it points to.

I brought the subject round to lists since you probably are trying to keep track of all receipts somewhere after creating them, and the list has an `add` function that will do that nicely for you.

If you want to print out the whole contents of the list, then you could have a loop:

```
for(String line:myList) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Also, I saw a post somewhere about making lists where the user suggested using the Set function instead, which would you judge be the most effective?

Comment: It looks like you want each receipt value to be remembered for outputting at the end. If you use a list, they'll be remembered in order. A set will remember them but in whatever order the set chooses to store them. Even though you're redefining `receipt`, the receipts you store in the list will be unaffected as per my explanation regarding references.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to append the new Strings. Alternatively, you can simply concatenate tow Strings with the `+`-Operator, but this is really inefficient in terms of execution time.

Comment: StringBuilder is used internally to do static concatenation - i.e. code that reads `String a = "b" + "c" + "d"` stuff, so is a good idea in general. Using + on the fly isn't perfect, but it won't kill you unless you're doing immense load. It's just a fairly weak practice.

Answer (score 0):

First you can declare an ArrayList of Strings:

```
ArrayList<String> receipts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then add the value of the receipt variable:

```
receipts.add(receipt);
```

At the end you can print all elements of ArrayList

```
for (String s : receipts)
     System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I want to do, but once the value of the reciept value has been added to the ArrayList can I using that method go trough the proccess which determines the value of receipt and then add that new value of receipt to the ArrayList, without the first reciept value added to the list being altered?

Edit: Spelling.

Comment: sorry I did not really understand what it is you need. If you give me a concrete example, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a StringBuilder, and keep on adding what you want in the loop, adding a newline to it at the end of the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    StringBuilder receipt;
    //Other variable initializations
```

Also, your while loop could probably be changed to a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ticketTotal; i++)
{
    receipt.append(zoneAmount);
    receipt.append(" zone(s), ");
    receipt.append(fareType);
    receipt.append(", bought at: ");
    receipt.append(purchaseLoc);
    receipt.append(". Your price: ");
    receipt.append(price);
    receipt.append(" SEK.\n");
}
```

Then when you need to just print your StringBuilder:

```
System.out.println(receipt.toString());
```